# Slow loading of images from database

Tags: performance, sqlite, filesystems, titanium, appcelerator

Greetings. `SDK 1.6.2`

I am storing the location of camera captures in a database along with some other information.

I have a window that loops thru the database and displays the images in small, tiled thumbnails.

The more images that I have the longer this window takes to load (remains blank until finished)

Here's how I'm calling the images:

```
var imageArray = [];
var images = [];

// open and parse database
var db = Titanium.Database.open('photoDB');

    var dbrows = db.execute('select id, date, image, tags from images order by date asc');

    while (dbrows.isValidRow()) {

        imagesArray.push({
        id: dbrows.fieldByName('id'),
            image:dbrows.fieldByName('image'), // image is the location of the stored image inside of applicationDataDirectory
            tags:dbrows.fieldByName('tags')
        }); 

        dbrows.next();
    }

    dbrows.close();

db.close();

// Load in the images
for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++){
    var pushleft = ((i % 4) * 76); // tile from left
    var pushtop = (Math.floor(i/4) * 100); //tile from top

    var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, imageArray[i].image);

    if(file.exists()){

        images[i] = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image: file.nativePath,
            width: 75,
            height: 96,
            left: pushleft,
            top: pushtop,
            store_id: imageArray[i].id,
            zIndex: 99
        });

        win.add(images[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the lag is due `getFile` or maybe the size of the images being stored?

I had 10 images stored and this window took 13 seconds to load. If I didn't know to wait I would think it was broken and left the app...

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my first suggestion would be that if you are only show an image with dimensions of 75 X 96; then why save the much larger image?

why dont you save a thumbnail of the image by resizing it first.

Also, what device are you on? IOS or Android?

Comment: Aaron, thanks for the reply. I'm saving the whole image because the whole image will be used and uploaded to a server later. `iOS`

Comment: i have the same situation, but i save two versions of the image. It might perform well over wi-fi, but if the application is to be used over 3G you will have a bad UX transferring that huge image back and forth over the wire...IMHO.

Comment: I'll give thumbnail creation a shot and let you know how it works. Thanks for the tip @Aaron Saunders, I'll report back soon.

Comment: creating separate thumbnail images increased the speed exponentially. Was hoping to refrain from storing multiple versions of the same image but if push comes to shove thats more acceptable than a tragically long load. Thanks @Aaron.